# webpack source map generation

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React application that uses webpack and would like to configure it to generate source maps to debug via the browser.

I added `devtool: 'eval-source-map'` to my *webpack.config.js*. My understanding is that should map the line numbers from the transpiled code to my source files for debugging.

I run my *develop* script (*npm run develop*) to run webpack. But when I open Chrome DevTools and expand the source, under *webpack-internal://*, the code does not match my source, but instead shows the transpiled format (e.g., "function _typeof(obj)", etc.).

Shouldn't this allow me to debug my original source (pre-babel transpilation) via Chrome DevTools, etc.?

My *develop* script in *package.json* is:

```
"develop": "webpack --mode development --watch",
```

My *webpack.config.js* is:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: "C:\\dev\\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\\webapps\\myapp"
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/proposal-class-properties']
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**Update**: Turns out this works for me in Firefox (I see the source code while debugging), but not Chrome. How can I get it to work in Chrome (via Chrome DevTools)?

Comment: Turns out this works in Firefox (I see the actual source code while debugging), but NOT in Chrome. How can I get it to work in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Chrome DevTools, then select Settings and check *Enable JavaScript sourcemaps*.